# Using <h:link> with a dynamic query string in "outcome"

Tags: jsf, query-string

In my JSF application I've got a link to a page, which is build with a dynamic query string:

```
<h:link outcome="list?#{controller.queryString}" value="Example" />
```

I can't use `<f:param>`, because the count of included parameters changes for every request.

The problem is that the query string is *URL encoded*, because some parameter values can contain a `=`. The result is that the query string is encoded twice in the result HTML.

An outcome of `list?a=b%3Dc` becomes:

```
<a href=".../list.xhtml?a=b%253Dc">Example</a>
```

Looking at the JSF spec (*Default NavigationHandler Algorithm*) I can't find anything about encoded in the query string. But I think that `com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.findImplicitMatch` is a rather *hacky* implementation.

My question: Did I use `<h:link>` in a wrong way (*works as designed*) or is this somehow a bug?

My current solution is to use a `<h:outputLink>` instead - which prevents the usage of any navigation rules.

Answer (score 3):

If `#{controller.queryString}` is at least view scoped or broader, then you could use a `Map<String, String>` with unencoded values instead and use `<c:forEach>` to dynamically generate `<f:param>` entries.

```
private Map<String, String> params;
```

```
<h:link ...>
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.params}" var="entry">
        <f:param name="#{entry.key}" value="#{entry.value}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:link>
```

If it is however request scoped (e.g. depends on user input), then you'd need to use a request scoped bean and explicitly rebuild the view as below in the action method before ajax-updating the link, so that JSTL tags run once again during render response.

```
String viewId = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
UIViewRoot view = context.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(context, viewId);
context.setViewRoot(view);
```

If the bean being request scoped is however not an option, then your best bet is manually generating the URL with help of [`ViewHandler#getBookmarkableURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#getBookmarkableURL-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-boolean-), passing the view ID and the parameters as a `Map`.

```
url = context.getApplication().getViewHandler().getBookmarkableURL(context, outcomeViewId, params, false);
```

```
<a href="#{bean.url}">...</a>
```

The outcome view ID is easy if you rely solely on implicit navigation.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/)

Comment: Unfortunately my parameters depend on some input values - they are request scoped and not available during _view build time_. What do you think about "bug or not"? I'm indifferent if I should report this.

Comment: Isn't the `<a>` solution just a replacement of my `<h:outputLink>` solution?  And rebuilding the view looks like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. In that case I would rather write a custom renderer which fixes that problem for all `<h:link>` in my application.